# Laravel 9 - updated picture not show in view

Tags: php, laravel, image, laravel-9

it is my first time using laravel 9, I'm making some CRUD, the problem is when I updating the data. The data was update/change in database but the picture that I update was not save in laravel folder. Can anyone help me?

Here's the update code:

```
public function edit(Request $request, $id)
{
    $student = Student::findOrFail($id);
    return view('edit', ['editstudent' => $student]);
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $student = Student::findOrFail($id);

    if ($request->file('image')) {
        // hapus gambar lama
        Storage::delete('image/' . $student->image);

        // simpan gambar baru
        // $path = $request->file('image')->store('public/image');
        $data = $request->all();
        if ($request->file('image')) {
            $extension = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $newName = $request->name . '-' . now()->timestamp . '.' . $extension;
            $path = $request->file('image')->store('image', $newName, 'public');

            $data['image'] = $newName; // Save the filename to the database.
        }
        $student->update($data);
    } else {
        $student->update($request->all());
    }

    $student->update($request->all());
    if ($student) {
        session()->flash('success', 'Data berhasil diubah');
        session()->flash('pesan', 'Data berhasil diubah');
    }

    return redirect('/about');
}
```

I made the update function somewhat the same as the save function.

The views:

```
@extends('layouts.templates')
@section('title', 'Detail')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>Student Detail</h1>
        <div class="my-3">
            <img src="{{ asset('storage/image/'.$student->image) }}" alt="{{ $student->name }}" style="width:100px">
        </div>
        <h3>Nama : {{$student->name}}</h3>
        <h3>Gender :
            @if ($student->gender == 'P')
            Perempuan
            @else
            Laki - laki
            @endif</h3>
        <h3>NIM : {{$student->NIM}}</h3>
        <a href="/about">Back</a>
    </div>
</div>


@endsection
```

forms:

```
@extends('layouts.templates')
@section('title', 'Edit Student')
@section('content')


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8 m-auto">
            <h2 class="my-3">Form Edit Student</h2>
            <form action="/update/{{$editstudent->id}}" method="post">
                @csrf
                @method('PUT')
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Nama </label>
                    <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                        placeholder="Masukkan Nama" value="{{$editstudent->name}}" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="gender">Gender</label>
                    <select name="gender" id="gender" class="form-control" required>
                        <option value="{{$editstudent->gender}}">{{$editstudent->gender}}</option>
                        @if ($editstudent->gender == 'L')
                        <option value="P">P</option>
                        @else
                        <option value="L">L</option>
                        @endif
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="NIM">NIM</label>
                    <input name="NIM" type="text" class="form-control" id="NIM" value="{{$editstudent->NIM}}">
                </div>
                <label for="image">Gambar</label>
                <div class="form-group">
                     <img src="{{ asset('storage/image/'.$editstudent->image) }}" alt="{{ $editstudent->name }}" style="width:100px">
                    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="image" name="image" value="{{$editstudent->image}}">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-10 mb-5">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <a href="/about">Back</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

Here's the error
Before update:

[The views before update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KvYR.png)

[In database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BL6NV.png)

[In laravel Storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0R0gV.png)

After update:

[Views after update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhXvB.png)

[Database after update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsRvA.png)

[The image don't change in laravel folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYCKs.png)

is there an error in my views? or an error in the update function?

Answer (score 0):

First you are missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on form.

Then for deleting something on public disk(disk info can be found on `config/filesystems.php`):

```php
Storage::disk('public')->delete('image/' . $user->image);
```

Use `storeAs` for naming:

```php
->storeAs('image', $newName, 'public')
```

```php
public function update(Request $request, User $user)
{
    $validated = $request->validate([
        'name' => ['required', 'string'],
        'image' => ['sometimes', 'required', 'file', 'image', 'max:1024']
    ]);

    if (isset($validated['image'])) {
        $file = $validated['image'];
        $extension = $file->extension();
        $newName = $validated['name'] . '-' . now()->timestamp . '.' . $extension;
        $path = $file->storeAs('image', $newName, 'public');

        $validated['image'] = $newName;

        Storage::disk('public')->delete('image/' . $user->image);
    }

    $user->update($validated);

    if ($user) {
        session()->flash('success', 'Data berhasil diubah');
        session()->flash('pesan', 'Data berhasil diubah');
    }

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

And based on laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#other-uploaded-file-information):

> However, keep in mind that the `getClientOriginalName` and `getClientOriginalExtension` methods are considered unsafe, as the file name and extension may be tampered with by a malicious user. For this reason, you should typically prefer the `hashName` and `extension` methods to get a name and an extension for the given file upload.

Comment: oke, it works finally, thank you